# How to Show only the Slice or Certain Portion of the image using CSS or JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I set two background images one above the other, Below image (Blue color with question mark) will stay as it is but the top background image (Yellow Color Image) needs to set according to the percentage as shown in the image, I tried to hack this by using CSS but couldn't get the exact solution for it. Can somebody help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Got any code to share?

Comment: If you are stuck, maybe you can cheat a bit, use 4 image for the yellow, 1 for 25%, 1 for 50%, ... and you just change image each time you need

Comment: I think this article may helps you : https://css-tricks.com/css-pie-timer/